# WPF project path setting

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

How to set path for a project in vs2010, so that it works in all systems without showing any path errors?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What went wrong? What path?

Comment: @Erno in my wpf application i have refferenced many dll's , so when i try to run on other systemIDE wont find those dll because of the local path of my system. Now i wanted to set PATH for my project so that it will run without that error in all systems

Comment: @dvvrd basically i need to set Environment Variable for my WPF project . In win32 is pretty easy you find that in properties->vc++Directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative path should be the same. You can set it as ..\..\..\ ( where .. is parent folder )
look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210754/visual-studio-relative-assembly-references-paths)

Comment: That worked pretty well thanx

Answer (score 0):

You could make a mapped drive using `subst` to the folder containing the dll's that you refer to.

When you open the solution on a different PC just create a mapped drive with the same name to the local path that contains the dll's

Make sure you always set the reference to dll's on the mapped drive.

This way you only have to remember to `subst` the correct path.